# iOS 15 Beta 7 & 8 - App process killed , when App consumes Bluetooth Asseceries framework in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, external-accessory

Application process being killed by iOS internal, when the application was background for more than 30 secs and application is consuming Bluetooth Asseceries frameworks (data transmission or just Bluetooth connected, no data transmission) or periodic network upload is progress in background

Not observed this issue in till iOS 15 beta 6. Observed after upgrading iOS version to 15 Beta 7 and 8

am I missing any new configuration to run the application in background other than External BLE Accessaries and Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories in Background ? is it Possible to run the application in background with above scenarios for 10 mins?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to run the App in background for 30 mins in above said scenarios?